# Flash tutorial for programmers

Tags: flash, actionscript

I am a programmer with a relatively good background programming in ActionScript using Flash Builder. However, I have been handed a FLA file meant to be opened in Flash CS 4, and I have to add some code to it, but this is the first time I've ever used this software in my life.

After I opened the file, I was greeted by a quite unhelpful interface (maybe it's friendly for artists?), and I immediately had questions such as:

1. How can I edit the source code?
2. How do I run the program?
3. How is the source code organized?
4. Where is the entry point of the program?
5. How can I do source control of these files?

I've been looking at flash tutorials online, but every tutorial starts with drawing shapes, tweening, the timeline, etc. Honestly, I don't care about any of those things (they've already been done by people at the design team).

I already know how to code in ActionScript, so what I need is a tutorial to give me a kickstart in coding -already designed- flash files using Flash (not Flash Builder).

Anybody knows of such a tutorial?

edit: I have been fighting against flash cs4 all day and I am very very disappointed with it. I thought I was good with technology, but it has been a really long time since I last found a tool so difficult to use and understand.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sounds like you might need to start at the beginning, Flash is not an easy programme to just jump into.

Having ActionScripting knowledge is good but if you have never worked within the IDE you are going to really struggle.

For great tutorials you could have a look at [www.flashkit.com](http://www.flashkit.com) I have learnt a lot from there and the people are very helpful in the forums.

> Quote:
>   I've been looking at flash tutorials
>   online, but every tutorial starts with
>   drawing shapes, tweening, the
>   timeline, etc. Honestly, I don't care
>   about any of those things (they've
>   already been done by people at the
>   design team).

You should really learn each of these things too, do a tutorial on each. Fair enough, it's already been done for you on this project but unless you know what's going on it will just continue to frustrate you, sorry.

**Book:**
This book really helped me get started it's old now but maybe you could get a cheap ebook of it from somewhere. "Flash MX ActionScript: The Designer's Edge". The fundamentals will be the same.

Tutorials:
Flashkit actionscripting section... http://www.flashkit.com/tutorials/Actionscripting/

Comment: I don't mind starting at the beginning, since that's the point of my original question. However, most tutorials seem to avoid AS like the plague, like "don't worry, flash is easy, you don't have to code". I just want a tutorial or book or whatever that doesn't treat me like a kid, and explains things properly. Take for instance the first page that comes out when you search "Flash CS4 tutorial". It has 32 steps, but only the 31st has AS in it, and 6 lines of it, for all it's worth. This is what I mean when I say a tutorial _for programmers_.

Comment: Added a book that really helped me and a link to actionscript tutorials. I think 95% of them use the official flash ide.

Answer (score 0):

First is it As2.0 or 3.0?

When you open your fla you should see the objects in the library, a timeline and a stage. You can add code straight into a keyframe in the timeline which is the preferred method in AS2.0 and the only method in AS3.0 (other than external files). This can be accessed by right clicking the keyframe and selecting the 'actions' options, (near the bottom). There is also a hotkey, F9, or 'fn' + F9 on mac I think. You can also just open the actions panel by selecting it in the 'view' menu in the top menu bar. In AS2.0 and below you can add code directly onto objects such as movieclips or buttons but this is not-advised as you cannot do it in AS3.0.

I hope this helps 
:)

Comment: Thanks for your comment. The ActionScript version is Flash Lite 1.1. However, since coding in Flash Builder (for AS 3.0) is quite similar to coding in Java, C++ or any other language, I would appreciate programmer-oriented definitions of "library", "timeline", "stage", "keyframe", "actions" etc. For instance, I just found that "Mask" means "Do not show", and why its icon is a hammer is completely outside of my understanding. I also find it bizarre that I can set a movieclip's initial values for _x and _y, but not for _visible. It's these things that I would like a thorough explanation of.

Comment: A mask does much more than just not show, it overlays the underlying layer and only shows the where the two layers meet. But anyway not the point... :)

Comment: @Kohan that seems to be true when the layer's icon is a black rectangle with a cyan oval inside, but when it's a hammer, it seems to do nothing else than "not show".

Comment: Is the hammer an image? Not sure if that would work. I would guess that it would just treat it as a square.

Comment: In flash Library is the where all your elements like movieclips or buttons are 'stored', this is local to the fla and is just the name of the window. Timeline is the window that contains the layers and keyframes, each layer has independent keyframes, layers will render on top of a layer that is below it. A keyframe is just a frame, like a frame in an animation as flash was initially built for animation, each keyframe acts as a separate picture in comic in a way.. Actions is what the window in which you write actionscript into is called.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you take another look at the tutorials you disregarded earlier. You can probably skip the portions regarding how to use the drawing tools, but most of them will include some sort of explanation of the timeline and the set-up of the Flash IDE. From there you will be able to move into editing the file, but without a knowledge of how the program works or how it is set up, editing it will be a nightmare. I would suggest the TotalTraining Flash CS4 video series - I think you can find it online and the lessons are broken down pretty specifically so you can just focus on the ones you will need to know.

Comment: It really irritates me that every tutorial I've seen so far seems like it was written for complete computer newbies, starting with "how to save your project" and having 20 steps to create a simple tween. I pretty much learned what I needed to know, and wrote the script I needed. However, I really think the internet could use a flash tutorial for adults.

Answer (score 0):

First, with the file open in the Flash application, open File > Publish Settings. Click the Flash tab. Does it say Script: ActionScript 3.0 ? If so, you can proceed. But if it is 2.0, or 1.0, I think you should see if an experienced Flash jockey can be hired to fix it, because it would be a big waste of your time to learn an old version of AS -- the differences are severe, and also, in earlier versions you would need to dig down into the timeline and open multiple objects to find and edit the script.

If it is ActionScript 3.0, you need to determine whether you have all the script. In the timeline, is there a layer named "actions"? If so, click frame 1 in that layer. Then open Window > Actions to view that code on that frame.

But if there is no layer named "actions," again, I think a Flash jockey must be hired. The potential for insane spaghetti code is great with Flash, and as someone who is new to it, if you have a badly scripted file, it just would not be worth the time to try to unravel it.

If it is AS3 and all (or most of) the script is on frame 1, you will probably be able to work with it, as AS3 is a lot like JavaScript.

NOTE: Flash Lite 1.1 is NOT the version of ActionScript. It is the player that the file was scripted to run in.

Comment: According to Adobe's documentation, "Flash Lite 1.1 ActionScript" is indeed a different version of ActionScript, which is a hybrid of Flash 4 ActionScript plus commands and properties for the Flash Lite player. If you read my post, you should know I'm having trouble with the Flash CS4 _user interface_, not ActionScript (regardless of the version) itself.

Comment: I stand corrected - I did search around a bit to find out more about Flash Lite 1.1, but I guess I didn't look hard enough. The reason I was asking is that in versions prior to AS3, code can be attached to/embedded in instances of objects that can be scattered throughout various Timelines - thus your unfamiliarity with the interface will be compounded.

Comment: No matter how much you learn about the interface, you might miss bits of code that are hidden. Most of the beginner books for Flash (e.g. Adobe Classroom in a Book) describe the Library, etc., with illustrations. But the UI for CS4 is very different from all previous versions, and a bit different from CS5 too.